# Error when trying to install Google Chrome

Tags: software-center, google-chrome

I have problems when trying to install Google Chrome on Ubuntu Software Center and Terminal.

**On Ubuntu Software Center**

[image: from Ubuntu Software Center]

**On Terminal**
[image: from the Terminal]

How do I install Google Chrome?

**UPDATE**

[image: new update]

I have tried `sudo apt-get install libxss1 libudev0` but I got this: [image: update on code]

Comment: hm.. try doing
`sudo apt-get install libxss1 libudev0`

Comment: @geoh I have updated my post with an image showing it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why but libudev0 is not shipped with raring, I think. (Atleast I dont know which package to install). But the deb files are there for [64 bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/libudev0/175-0ubuntu19) and [32 bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/libudev0/175-0ubuntu19)

So, please do the following

For 64 bit machines,

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/132294155/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb
```

For 32 bit machines,

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/132294322/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_i386.deb
```

This installs Chrome

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

1. The first command downloads the .deb installer for libudev0
2. The second command installs the libudev0
3. The third command installs google chrome

This works for me :)

Comment: Thanks. I found the files here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/FyszF27mzIc too!

Answer (score 2):

The package has been removed that Ubuntu require for Chrome to work. You can look more into it here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/libudev0

**x64**

Download `libudev0_175-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb` from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/119461136/libudev0_175-0ubuntu13_amd64.deb

**x86**

http://launchpadlibrarian.net/132294322/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_i386.deb

From: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/FyszF27mzIc